# Magento2 UI Component Password and Confirm Password validation is not working

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In magento2, I have added form fields by UI component where there are tow fields, password and password_confirmation.
While saving that form if there are mismatch in password and password_confirmation fields, validation is not working.

Below is the code for UI component file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">designnbuy_user_form.user_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">designnbuy_user_form.user_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">designnbuy_user_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">designnbuy_user_form</item>
        </item>

        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
        <item name="childrenFromMeta" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="user_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Model\User\DataProvider</argument>
            <!--<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy\Workflow\Ui\DataProvider\User\Form\UserDataProvider</argument>-->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">user_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>


    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User Information</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="user_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">user_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable User</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_active</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="username">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">username</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="firstname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">firstname</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="lastname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">lastname</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="password">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/js/components/text</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/form/element/password</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Password</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-admin-password" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="password_confirmation">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/js/components/text</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/form/element/password</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Password Confirmation</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">password_confirmation</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-cpassword" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="role_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Designnbuy\Workflow\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Role\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Workflow Role</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">role_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="notify_user">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Notify User by Mail</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">notify_user</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="current_user_verification_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Current User Identity Verification</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="current_password">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/form/element/password</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Password</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">User</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">current_password</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-admin-password" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post your code in ui_component file?

Comment: I have edited and posted ui component source

Comment: @Ajay : were you able to solve this issue?I am facing the same problem and unable to find any working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<field name="password">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Designnbuy_Workflow/form/element/password</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Password</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Try following way:

```
<field name="password">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/password</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Password</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

---

Create password.html

```
Designnbuy/Workflow/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/password.html
<input class="input-text" type="password" data-bind="
    hasFocus: focused,
    value: value,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code below inside the validation item.

```
<item name="equalTo" xsi:type="string">password</item>
```

Hope it will help you!